# Go "unknown token" and ": or newline expected"

Tags: go

I'm implementing various data structures and algorithims in GO, and in my first run at a BST I'm getting the following error on this code:

```
func insert(t Tree, k Node) {
    var newT Tree

    if t.root==nil {
        t.setRoot(k)
    }

    else if k.key < t.root.key {
        newT.setRoot(t.root.lc, newT)
        insert(newT,k)
    }
    else {
        newT.setRoot(t.root.rc, newT)
        insert(newT,k)
    }

}
```

The line:

```
 // else is highlighted as an "unknown token" the bracket is ": or newline expected" and everything else is "unknown token"
    else {
        newT.setRoot(t.root.rc, newT)
        insert(newT,k)
    }
```

Looking at this:

https://gobyexample.com/if-else

It looks like this should work, so I'm confused what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`else` must be on the same line as `}` because of automatic semicolon insertion between `}` and the end of the line.

```
func insert(t Tree, k Node) {
    var newT Tree

    if t.root == nil {
        t.setRoot(k)
    } else if k.key < t.root.key {
        newT.setRoot(t.root.lc, newT)
        insert(newT, k)
    } else {
        newT.setRoot(t.root.rc, newT)
        insert(newT, k)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself writing:

```
 if ... {
 } else if ... {
 } else if ...
```

It is probably better to move to `switch`:

```
switch {
   case ...: blah
   case ...: blahblah
   case ...: blahblahblah
}
```

In your case, that would be:

```
switch {
  case t.root == nil: t.setRoot(k)
  case k.key < t.root.key:
    newT.setRoot(t.root.lc, newT)
    insert(newT, k)
  default:
    newT.setRoot(t.root.rc, newT)
    insert(newT, k)
}
```

Comment: Other than as a "goism" why is this better?  It's not particularly clearer to me coming from the background I have.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner 3 is roughly the point where I would go from if/else to switch. At least to me, it is about as clear, no matter how many conditionals you have and at roughly 3, I find it no less readable than if/else sequences. In many cases (not this one, though), that's also where you have a focus for more conditionals being added.

Comment: I'm not saying it is or isn't clearer, but I was wondering why you would say "better".  I assumed you meant that there was some objective measure of why (a performance increase or something).  Is it simply that go lets you use switch statements this way and its prettier?  ( I do agree it's prettier =))

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner Ah, with "better", I mean "clearer".